# pandas: Extracting the index of the maximum value in an expanding window

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas DataFrame, I can create a Series B with the maximum value of another Series A, from the first row to the current one, by using an expanding window:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].expanding().max()
```

I can also extract the value of the index of the maximum *overall* value of Series A:

```
idx_max_A = df['A'].idxmax().value
```

What I want is an efficient way to combine both; that is, to create a Series B that holds the value of the index of the maximum value of Series A from the first row up to the current one. Ideally, something like this...

```
df['B'] = df['A'].expanding().idxmax().value
```

...but, of course, the above fails because the `Expanding` object does not have `idxmax`. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

---

**EDIT**: For illustration purposes, for the following DataFrame...

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 3, 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], columns=['A'])
```

...I'd like to create an additional column B so that the DataFrame contains the following:

```
   A  B
a  1  a
b  2  b
c  1  b
d  3  d
e  0  d
```

Comment: Can you create a sample with an expected output? It'd be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Added a sample!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use `expanding` + `max` + `groupby`:

```
v = df.expanding().max().A
df['B'] = v.groupby(v).transform('idxmax')

df

   A  B
a  1  a
b  2  b
c  1  b
d  3  d
e  0  d
```

Comment: This works, but what does `group-by-a-Series` mean conceptually?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `idmax` is a function in the latest version of pandas which I don't have yet. Here's a solution not involving groupby or idmax

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 1, 3, 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], columns=['A'])
temp = df.A.expanding().max()

df['B'] = temp.apply(lambda x: temp[temp == x].index[0])
df

    A   B
a   1   a
b   2   b
c   1   b
d   3   d
e   0   d
```

Comment: Thanks Haleemur, but that doesn't do it: the output of `df['A'].expanding().max().idxmax().value` is the single index corresponding to the max value of `df['A']` overall...

Comment: ah, I misunderstood. I see you've added a sample expected output.

Comment: yup, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you're right, the answer was given before the sample output was posted. I'll update the answer so that the result in your answer is obtained for pandas versions prior to 20.